# Filling combobox with data from php database and Submit

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys I am trying to filling db from php mysql to combobox  its work to show data but i can't submit when i am trying to add value in the option. Column i want to show is LawGroup.

[image]

Here is code that show data

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                        <select name="idlawgroup" id="custom-select" width="300" style="width: 300px">
                        <?php
                            $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM lawgroup");
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                            {
                              ?>
                              <option><?php echo $row["NameLawGroup"]; ?> </option>
                              <?php
                            }
                              ?>
                            
                           
                        </select> 
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $lawgroup_err;?></span>
                    </div>
```

And this is the code i want to add value

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                        <select name="idlawgroup" id="custom-select" width="300" style="width: 300px">
                        <?php
                            $res=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM lawgroup");
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                            {
                              ?>
                              <option value="$row["IDLawGroup"]"><?php echo $row["NameLawGroup"]; ?> </option>
                              <?php
                            }
                              ?>
                        </select> 
                        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $lawgroup_err;?></span>
```

Comment: You've missed a `<?php echo ... ?>` for `<option value="$row["IDLawGroup"]">`

Answer (score 0):

As @TheBoiYouLost pointed out in the comment section of the question, the problematic line is

```
<option value="$row["IDLawGroup"]"><?php echo $row["NameLawGroup"]; ?> </option>
```

Fix:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row["IDLawGroup"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["NameLawGroup"]; ?> </option>
```